# Triggering Events from html5 video player with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to show() a div when my html5 video player reaches a certain time. 
I was able to get a div to show at the end of the video, but I'm not sure how to show the div when the video is at a specific time, like 0:06.

```
<div id = "showdiv" style="display:none" align="center">
        this is the message that will pop up.
</div>

<video id='myVideo' align="center" margin-top="100px" class='video-js 
       vjs-default-skin' preload='auto' data-setup='{}' width='800' height='446'>
<source src='myVideo.mp4' type='video/mp4'l></source>
<script>
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);  
function myHandler(e) {
    if(!e) { e = window.event; }
    $("#showdiv").toggle("slow");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `timeupdate` event. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/timeupdate

```
var runAtTime = function(handler, time) {
 var wrapped = function() {
     if(this.currentTime >= time) {
         $(this).off('timeupdate', wrapped);
         return handler.apply(this, arguments);
    }
 }
 return wrapped;
};

$('#myVideo').on('timeupdate', runAtTime(myHandler, 3));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/XTEWW/1/

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that doesn't seem to work for me. Must have something to do with .addEventListener('timeupdate', runAtTime(myHandler, 6), false);

Comment: it worked, but my time is like:- 01:00 minutes and second and can also takes hours like 03:01:00, so how can i achieve this?

Comment: @UmairMalik convert it to seconds `h*60*60 + m*60 + s`

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!