# Triggering Events using Handler from html5 video player with JQuery

Tags: html, video, timeline

I'm using this method (found on stack Overflow) of executing an event when scrubbing an HMTL video:
[Triggering Events from html5 video player with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691054/triggering-events-from-html5-video-player-with-jquery)

it works perfectly. However er I'm at loss on how to trigger a different event when scrubbing the video timeline backwards to a previous (earlier) time. I'd like to toggle off the event and maybe add a different event when the user reaches the previous original time.

I'm using this method to 'scrub' the timeline:

```
var windowwidth = $(window).width()-20;

var scrollpos = window.pageXOffset/200;
var targetscrollpos = scrollpos;
var accel = 0;

// ---- Values you can tweak: ----
var accelamount = 0.1; //How fast the video will try to catch up with the target position. 1 = instantaneous, 0 = do nothing.

// pause video on load
vid.pause();


window.onscroll = function(){
    //Set the video position that we want to end up at:
    targetscrollpos = window.pageXOffset/200;   
};

setInterval(function(){  
      //Accelerate towards the target:
      scrollpos += (targetscrollpos - scrollpos)*accelamount;
      //update video playback
      vid.currentTime = scrollpos;
     vid.pause();
}, 60);
```

and this code from previous stack overflow question to trigger event(s)

```
    $(".boxB").animate({ marginLeft:'0px'},400);
    $(".boxA").animate({ width:'620px'}, 400);
}

var runAtTime = function(handler, time) {
     var wrapped = function() {
         if(this.currentTime >= time) {
             $(this).off('timeupdate', wrapped);
             return handler.apply(this, arguments);
        }
     }
    return wrapped;
};

$('#v0').on('timeupdate', runAtTime(myHandler, 3.5));
```

A working version exist here:
http://www.mediaflash.ca/swipe_video_timeline/index.html

The function will only work if you use a scroll wheel mouse and scroll left and right or swipe left/right on iOS device.

Comment: So you want to know if the user scrubbed backwards or forward in time? Just store the last seen time with your element and at next scrub event check if the new time is bigger or smaller than the time before. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes I believe that is exactly what I want to do. I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Do you think I can salvage the method I'm currently using, or should I be using a different approach altogether? I'm guessing "if(this,currentTime <= 2.5 (or whatever other number I choose)..then... I don't know what then.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no separate event that is available for forward/backward scrolling.

What you can do to check if the user scrolled backwards is to store the last time and compare it to the new scrub time, like this:

```
var m_lastVideoTime = 0;//global scope

var runAtTime = function(handler, time) {

     var wrapped = function() {
         if (m_lastVideoTime < this.currentTime){
           //user scrolled back in time, do what you like here
         }
         m_lastVideoTime = this.currentTime;
         if(this.currentTime >= time) {
             //time exceeded specified value (3.5)
             $(this).off('timeupdate', wrapped);
             return handler.apply(this, arguments);
        }
     }
    return wrapped;
};
```

Your current function name runAtTime is a little misleading because it runs whenever the video time updates. However, it already turns itself off when the time 3.5 was exceeded.

From that moment, the runAtTime function currently is never called again until the page reloaded because you attach it only once using the .on jquery function.

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution, thank you for posting it. I've tried various ways of implementing it but am not at all sure how to do so correctly. I'm still experimenting